# Access a folder from a server on Android

Tags: android, url

If I want to access folders that are uploaded on a server, how would I access it from the Android project? I tried to use the following

```
public URL(String protocol, String host, String file)
```

**My Codes:**

```
URL url = new URL("file", "www.websitename.com", "/folderX");
MyClassName path = new MyClassName(url);
```

Seems like it couldn't access the folder on the server still. Is there anything that I miss or I should be using some other ways? There are no errors in the logcat so I am not sure what is it. No MalformedURLException being thrown as well.

Comment: Have you ever considered exposing your server's file system via a web service?

Comment: what does that means? can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

I you want to access the folder and its files from your server you need FTP account details to connect to your server from your android device.There are more FTP Client libraries available to access the files one of them is
http://commons.apache.org/net/download_net.cgi